# Curious about groupby function in pandas , how to write groupby for a generic dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, pandas-groupby

i want to write a generic function for groupby , suppose i have dataset which has around 100 columns  , for example it has 70 categorical column , 30 numeric attributes , now i would like to write a generic python function which will just take the dataset and will display appropriate groupby results in form on plots or data , any expert advice before i start into this ?

Thanks,
Shivam

Comment: One of the Zen's of Python is: "Explicit is better than implicit".  Groupby can't magically predict what you want, nor should it have to because it's already general purpose.

Comment: yeah agree with you mostly , but anyways i am just trying to make it random by categories and grouping atleat 10 numerical attributes as of now.

Answer (score 0):

You could incorporate the random module from the standard library to get a random sample of all numeric columns.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'a': list('abcde'),
        'b': ['1','2','3','4','5'],
        'c': range(5),
        'd': [i*21 for i in range(5)],
        'e': [12,32,45,67,54]})

str_cols = df.select_dtypes(exclude='number').columns.tolist()
num_cols = random.sample(df.select_dtypes('number').columns.tolist(), k=2)
dff = df.loc[:, str_cols+num_cols]
print(dff)

   a  b   d  c
0  a  1   0  0
1  b  2  21  1
2  c  3  42  2
3  d  4  63  3
4  e  5  84  4
```

Comment: Yes exactly like this i am planning as of now as i can't groupby all the categories in one go but at least of sample of 5 or 10 would be great to show . thanks for your reply